# Categorising clothing based on keywords in title

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm looking for the best way to categorise items based on keywords that may be found in the title for a clothing website please.

The categories will be the gender of the clothing item, so womens, mens, boys, girls.  However, depending on the item, the titles may contain different keywords such as 'female', 'woman', 'women', 'lady's' and so on.

My thoughts are to put the keywords into a list and then cycle through the list looking for a match and then categorise accordingly.

If I follow this method though, is it possible to do this with a list within a list and cycle through that, so we could have:

```
gender = ['woman', [#keywords for females clothes], 'men', [#keywords for men's clothes]]
```

Then cycle through this and if we find a match, tag it accordingly.  Alternatively it may be better to use a dictionary, have the key be the category and then a list of corresponding keywords.

Or, there could be an altogether different solution that I've completely missed.  I feel there is a pretty simple solution to this but for some reason I can't seem to get my head around it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dictionaries or sets work better for this than lists - with the sample you provided in your question, you would have to manually figure out how to divide the list. I would recommend either having a list of sets (where each set of keywords corresponds to the same thing) or using a dict (e.g. with 'woman' as a key and the list of keywords as the value). You might also search for information on "fuzzy" keyword matching (python's `fuzzywuzzy` module is made for this), depending on how you need the algorithm to work.

Comment: I'd recommend trying to actually implement a few different approaches, experiment with how they work relative to each other, and then maybe post to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), which would be better-equipped to recommend more efficient approaches.

Comment: Can you provide more details as to what is your end goal ,whether you are working with web scraping, NLP , ML or something else , and if the data you will be dealing with will be large or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'men': ['men', 'boy'], 'women': ['women', 'girl', 'lady']}

def classify(text):
    gender = 'None of any'
    for i in d:
        if any(j in text for j in d[i]):
            gender = i
    return gender

df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['this is a boy', 'a girl']})
df['cat'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: classify(x))
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks, the dual for loop with the dictionary and list is what I was after, I just couldn't get my head around how this would work.

Answer (score -1):

you can use flashtext for extracting keyword from a given string

```
 from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
 kp = KeywordProcessor()
 dict_= {'sport': ['cricket','football'],'movie' : ['horror', 'drama']} # here you can add list of word for men and woman

 kp.add_keywords_from_dict(dict_)

 # now you can extract keyword from a given string
 kp.extract_keywords('I love playing football')
 #op
 ['sport']

 kp.extract_keywords("some people don't like to watch drama and horror movie, but love to watch cricket")
 #op
 ['movie', 'movie', 'sport']
```

Comment: situl you can refer to the docs https://readthedocs.org/projects/flashtext/downloads/pdf/latest/